# Python script to test game

Tags: python, testing, reversi

I've written a game entitled reversi.py that I want to write a script for to aid in testing. The game is AI based and takes a good amount of time to run. I was hoping to write a script to run the game and output it's results to a file so I could run the game x amount of times while I go do other things and come back to it. I'm stuck at trying to call the game from the script file. Here is what I have so far:

```
from games import *
from reversi import *

def main():

    f = open('Reversi Test', 'w')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the game already output its results to a file?

Comment: No it doesn't, it just prints to the screen. I need more direction on how to go about calling a function in a different file and writing the results.

Comment: Prints to the screen... to the terminal, or to a GUI? If its to a GUI (and you can't modify it), then you're out of luck.

Comment: Yeah I meant the terminal. Sorry about that.

Comment: What OS are you using? If it prints to the terminal, and you are have access to a `bash` terminal (e.g. Linux, OSX), then just something as simple as `run_program > output.txt` will work!

Comment: I'm using OS X. Would that be part of the subprocess module?

Comment: You can do it via the `subprocess` module, yes, but i'm trying to say I don't think this is has to be a python quesiton, the simpler way is to just dump the output of the program into a file using the `bash` shell in the Terminal program, instead of python (the `>` character does in `bash`, essentially it says "pipe everything from the left into the file name in the left")

Comment: Oh okay! I see what you are saying now. Thank you! I'll look more into the bash idea.

Comment: just import sys and redefine sys.stdout. something like import sys sys.stdout = open("filename", 'w')

Answer (score 0):

If the program writes to standard output, then just redirect it to the some other file. Something like the following

```
import sys

from games import *
from reversi import *

def main():

    N = 100
    for i in range(N):
       sys.stdout = open('Reversi_Test_' + str(i), 'w')
       game() # call your method here
       sys.stdout.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can also use the `with` statement:

```
from future import with_statement
import sys

from games import *
from reversi import *

def main():

    N = 100
    for i in range(N):
       with open('Reversi_Test_' + str(i), 'w') as sys.stdout:
           game() # call your method here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```